# Is there a way to detect users select all content?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor5

I'm implementing a plugin and have a use case need to detect when user select all content. I trying create a select all selection like this `const selectAllSelection = editor.model.createSelection(editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'in')` and compare with current `model.document.selection` but they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Those selections are a bit different as the one created with `createSelection()` will start directly in `<$root>`. Real document selection will start inside the first `<paragraph>`. That makes the comparison a bit tricky.

But, it's not that bad:

- check whether the selection has just one range,
- get the first range of document selection (`selection.getFirstRange()`) and use `model.createRangeIn( editor.model.document.getRoot() )` to create a range inside the root,
- the ranges will differ due to what I described, so we can't do `range.isEqual()`. We need to check the start and end positions with `isTouching()`.

This would look more or less like this:

```
function doesSelectAll( selection ) {
    if ( selection.rangeCount != 1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    const firstSelectionRange = selection.getFirstRange();
    const rootRange = editor.model.createRangeIn( editor.model.document.getRoot() );

    return firstSelectionRange.start.isTouching( rootRange.start ) && firstSelectionRange.end.isTouching( rootRange.end );
}
```